# Add text before the price

Tags: woocommerce

I've been trying for days to add "price" before the product price inside woo commerce single product page. I've tried many variations of this code to no avail.

```
   /** Add "Price" before the price */
function price_text() {

?>

<div class="price-text">
<p>Price</p>
</div>

<?php

} 
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price','price_text');
```

This is the closest I've got, but it shows the price being $0.

I've also started to add this piece of code

```
'<span class="amount">' . $currency_symbol . $price . '</span>'
```

to no avail.but

I am really new to PHP and OPP in general. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using the Genesis framework if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 4):

A little improvement to be translatable.

```
/** Add "Price" before the price */
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price','price_text');

function price_text($price) {
  if ( is_woocommerce()){ ?>
<div class="price-text">
  <p><?php _e('Price','woothemes'); ?></p>
</div>
<?php
 return $price;
 } 
else {
        return $price;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this improves it?

Answer (score 3):

Yay!

I figured it out!

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price','price_text');
function price_text($price) {

?>

<div class="price-text">
<p>Price</p>
</div>

<?php

return $price;

}
```

I was just missing the variable

`$price`

when declaring the function

`price_text`

and

```
return $price;
```

Hope this helps somebody:)

Cheers,
Mike

Answer (score 1):

I added an if else statement so that it only shows on the product pages and not the checkout pages.

```
/** Add "Price" before the price */
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price','price_text');
function price_text($price) {
    if ( is_woocommerce()){
?>

<div class="price-text">
<p>Price</p>
</div>
<?php

return $price;

} 
else {
        return $price;
    }
}
```

Cheers,
Mike